# Rotating words with CSS animation. How do I stop at the last word?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am looking to make a word in a sentence to rotate between multiple options of words automatically with CSS. I want the word to stop at the last word and stay there. How could I do this using html/css?

Here is a link to the codepen.

https://codepen.io/nkangzing/pen/EwyqqM

```
<style>
.text-wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .animated-words {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .animated-words span:nth-child(2) { 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
        -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
        animation-delay: 3s; 
        color: #6b889d;
    }
    .animated-words span:nth-child(3) { 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
        -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
        animation-delay: 6s; 
        color: #6b739d; 
    }
    .animated-words span:nth-child(4) { 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
        -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
        animation-delay: 9s; 
        color: #7a6b9d;
    }
    .animated-words span:nth-child(5) { 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
        -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
        animation-delay: 12s; 
        color: #8d6b9d;
    }
    .animated-words span:nth-child(6) { 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; 
        -ms-animation-delay: 15s; 
        animation-delay: 15s; 
        color: #9b6b9d;
    }
    .animated-words span {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #6b969d;
        -webkit-animation: animateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
        -ms-animation: animateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
        animation: animateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animateWord {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
        5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
        17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
        20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
        80% { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
    }

</style>
<div class="text-wrapper">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy&nbsp;
    <div class="animated-words">
        <span class="am1">dog.</span>
        <span class="am1">horse.</span>
        <span class="am1">frog.</span>
        <span class="am1">cat.</span>
        <span class="am1">mouse.</span>
        <span class="am1">rabbit.</span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is a link to an example https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3RotatingWords/

The word keeps looping or just disappears at the end depending on if I put infinite to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full [link](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/eGdNRX).

First, change the animation property from infinite to linear:

```
animation: animateWord 18s linear 1 0s;
```

Then, for the last name, I don't run the first animation, but another one that looks like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateWordLast {
    0% { opacity: 0; } 
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

To make the last word stay longer (but not forever), adding these at the end seems to do the job:

```
.animated-words .last {
    -webkit-animation: animateWordLast 100s linear 1 18s;
    animation: animateWordLast 100s linear 1 18s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateWordLast {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Check `100s` duration, you can put a big number there, say 3600 (1 hr), and `18s` the delay of this second animation.

Comment: Ok, check my edited answer, or the pen link. If it solves the problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: It looks like your word character is missing the animation to ease it in. It just appears sudddenly.

Comment: So what is happening with your animate word 100s and the 0% opacity, the last word is losing the proper transition. Any ideas?

Comment: So actually we need animation-fill-mode:forwards in the .animated-words .last css rules. That will allow the last word to persist and keep the correct animation.

Comment: The second animation just makes the element opacity 1 for 100 seconds (or more if you need it to stay forever), after the first animation finishes (that's the reason there is a delay of 18s in the 2nd animation)

Answer (score -1):

I can't get any of these to work for me .... I'm using similar one with rotating words, and I changed my linear infinite to just linear like you said (not shown)

```css
            .rotateWords{
              -webkit-animation: rotateWords 12s linear 1 0s;
            -moz-animation: rotateWords 12s linear 1 0s;
            -o-animation: rotateWords 12s linear 1  0s;
            -ms-animation: rotateWords 12s linear 1 0s;
          animation: rotateWords 12s linear 1 0s;
            }
            .rotating-words:nth-child(2) {
            -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
            -o-animation-delay: 2s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
            animation-delay: 2s;
            }
           .rotating-words:nth-child(3) {
            -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
            -o-animation-delay: 4s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
          }
          .rotating-words:nth-child(4) {
          -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
            -o-animation-delay: 6s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
          animation-delay: 6s;  
    }
        .rotating-words:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
            -o-animation-delay: 8s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
          animation-delay: 8s;  
        }
        .rotate-last:nth-child(6) {  
        -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
            -o-animation-delay: 12s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
          animation-delay: 12s;
        }
    
    @keyframes rotateWords {
      0% {
        opacity: 0 ;
      }
      8% {
        opacity: 1 ;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }
      10% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```